Reading text files. Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines
I am trying to read and print text with python code but in colab, only last 5000 lines are printed and in python, it prints even less than that.
I have tried this code.
import sys

def get_filename():
    """Prompts the user for a filename and returns it."""
    filename = input("Enter a filename: ")
    return filename

def process_file(filename):
    """Reads the contents of a file and prints each line to the terminal."""
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
        for line in file:
            sys.stdout.write(line)  # Write each line to stdout
            sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    """Calls get_filename and then calls process_file with the name returned by get_filename."""
    filename = get_filename()
    process_file(filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


in python, it prints even less than that What do you mean by "in python"?  What exact command are you using?

I would guess that the problem is your output terminal does not have a big enough enough scrollback buffer to allow you to scroll all the way up to the beginning of the file.

How are you figuring out the exact number of lines printed?

I would try checking your terminal settings. Most terminals have a configurable limit of how many lines of output they will store and allow you to scroll back to see.

In colab it says: 'Streaming output truncated to the last 5000 lines.' While in cmd, I didn't get even 500 lines approximately. What command terminal should I use for it to work correctly?

I am using cmd terminal to run the .py file

Experiencing similar in colab, resolved as follows:

declare a counter (e.g. cnt=n)
in your for-loop, have the counter increment and stop where you want it to (in this example at 10th iteration:

for line in file:
  if cnt<=10:
    print(line)      
  else:
    break
  cnt+=1

